# Amount of Rent For Reimbursement

Tags: arithmetic

I have a business and I work from home. My accountant says I can reimburse myself for a portion of the rent I pay (**$1,500**). How can I calculate the money I can reimburse based on the amount of space I occupy while I am working (**25 square feet** out of a total **840 square feet**) and the time that I use that space (**40 hours per week**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that \$1500 is for 28 days. The rent per hour is \$1500/(28 days*24hours/day), so the rent for 4 weeks of 40 hours is $$\$1500\frac{4\cdot 40}{28\cdot24}$$But this is for the entire surface. You are using only 25/840 of it, so the final answer is
$$\$1500\frac{4\cdot 40\cdot 25}{28\cdot24\cdot 840}$$